# Can I make a fake PayPal donate button in the SandBox for testing?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, donations

I would like to set up a fake donate page using a PayPal donate button that goes to a sandbox account. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register this page: https://developer.paypal.com/

Then you can use the paypal API like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a test HTML file.</p>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----...[Encrypted message]...-----END PKCS7-----">

<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, though I'm unclear how to connect the donation button to my sandbox account. Any idea? Am I just not seeing it here?

Comment: After you've created your account at developer.paypal.com you can create actual sandbox seller and buyer accounts.  You'll need to create your seller account, and then you can launch that account and login to it just like a regular PayPal account.  Once in there you can create a donate button using the button manager in your profile, and that button can be used for testing on your website.

Comment: @AndrewAngell That was my first assumption, but there's password associated with test accounts by which I may sign in, and when I try the "I forgot my password" route, the test email can not be found. Any other ideas?

Comment: @AndrewAngell Hi, I tried to login my buyer account like a regular paypal account but I can't login. It says `Some of your info isn't correct. Please try again.` Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Any emails sent within the sandbox system never go to an actual email.  They only go to the Test Email tab within your developer.paypal.com account.

That said, you can always just create a new buyer or seller account, and use that one.  You create the password when you create the account.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create your sandbox account, you can obtain the "fake" donation button from the sandbox paypal buttons url: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/buttons/

Until we found this, we couldn't test the donation buttons.